# How to encode special font to JSON in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [image] => http://domain/photogal/tues/image/2012octo30big11.jpg
            [news] => 'ssN ^mj³ ho¡nÂ dm¼nse¯nb tamUÂ<br>
    '
        )
)
```

I encoded this array to json and get result like this

```
   [{"image":"http:\/\/domain\/photogal\/tues\/image\/2012octo30big11.jpg",
"news":"'ssN ^mj"}]
```

almost all part of news not in json string. How do json encode to this array?

Comment: You might want to consider using [base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) on the news string prior to json_encode, and then you'll have to of course [base64_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) it on the receiving end.

Comment: Other option is to convert your 'news' to UTF-8..
You can try with mb_convert_encoding..

Comment: thank you  cale_b i got the result using base64_encode() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try putting UTF-8 header before any other PHP code?

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

At my test your array was converted to this :

```
    {"image":"http:\/\/domain\/photogal\/tues\/image\/2012octo30big11.jpg",
"news":"'ssN ^mj\u00b3 ho\u00a1n\u00c2 dm\u00bcnse\u00afnb tamU\u00c2
    \r\n\t'"}
```

And after that with json_decode was back to original without losing any symbols..